# Syncing dnode and Express authentication - How?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dnode

I'm building a web app with Express and dnode and I'm trying to synchronize authentication between the two.

I found the following example, but the `sessionCheck` event doesn't appear to be firing on the connection object: http://repos.io/project/github/tblobaum/dnode-session/

Anybody have input for how to correctly synchronize auth between Express and dnode using sessions?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

It's relatively complicated but this is the simplest method without introducing a dependency.